# Automation: how to send the subscriber's data to one admin email?

Tags: email, automation

For Instance, I have a Data Extension called `DataExtensionName` with the sample data below.  And I want to send the exact 3 email messages (with the particular data: email/content in the message) to an admin email address: admin@example.com and not to the subscribers' email address.

```
|             email |  content |
|-------------------|----------|
| test1@example.com | content1 |
| test1@example.com | content2 |
| test1@example.com | content3 |
```

Expected output: `admin@example.com` should receive 3 email messages (intended to 3 subscribers) in inbox:

1st email message: `test1@example.com` content1

2nd email message: `test2@example.com` content2

3rd email message: `test3@example.com` content3

It won't matter where the email message comes from, as long as admin@example.com will receive it.
It won't matter as well if the subscribers would receive it or not, as long as admin@example.com will receive it (similar to **CC** or **BCC**).

Is there a way for this via automation (daily)?  I know there is a way via Guided Send where somewhere in the 4th step, there is this `Testing Options > Send all emails to` textbox where you can place an email address as recipient to email messages of say 3 subscribers.

Any shared ideas are highly appreciated. C",)